# Making a follow camera in Motionbuilder

Tags: animation

I am using VICON c3d files of someone walking, and I want to change the point of view to be first person. I started by setting the original camera to eye level, but when the character starts walking, the camera doesn't follow the eyes, so it turns into a view from behind.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't programming related on any level whatsoever. But if you want an answer, its that you need to constrain the camera to the head/eyes so that it follows the eyes in the first-person manner you want.